# Can you display the mobile 'email address' keyboard without input[type=email]?

Tags: html, input, email-validation

In the web app I'm working on usernames are *usually* email addresses - but not always. I'd therefore like to aid most users by displaying the "email address" keyboard to mobile visitors without actually validating the field as an email address.

Answer (score 1):

[MDN's guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) suggests that

```
<input type="text" inputmode="email" />
```

will provide the combination I need - but that this isn't currently supported by any browsers (Feb 2015). Does anyone know of better solutions that don't involve user-agent sniffing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [*novalidate* attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-novalidate) to skip field validation retaining the type *email*.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - I looked into novalidate but it seems to act at the form level rather than the input level? If so then this would mean other changes in our use case, e.g. we use the "required" attribute on the username and password fields and use HTML5 form validation to prevent submission without either value.

Comment: It seems that's not an official attribute, supported by some browsers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216115/override-html5-validation